# Get information from nested loop to render jsx conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

i have an object in which i have to loop two times to check what should i render in react.

My attemps:

```
// categories is my nested object
const checkedCategories = [...categories];

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
  for (let j =0; j < categories[i].products.length; j++){
    const currentImageType = categories[i].products[j].imageTypes;

    // get information from action in store(mobx) to check if image exists
    const image = images.getDefault(currImageType);

    if (image) {
      //error cannot add property visible, object is not extensible
      checkedCategories[i].visible = true;
    }
  }
}

const categoryTabs = checkedCategories.map((category, index) => {
  if (category.visible){
    return (
      <Product
          key={category.name}
          product={category.products}
       />
    )
  }
});
```

I want to find out how to solve a problem with not extensible object and render only  which has image (information from store which i got from nested loop)

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but looking at your code, this seems incorrect:  `for (let j =0; j < categories[i].products[j].length; j++){`.  Did you mean `for (let j =0; j < categories[i].products.length; j++){`?

Comment: Yes, of course, but there is a problem with this error:
//error cannot add property visible, object is not extensible

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your loops.  If you change your loops to the below, it should work.  The code below is cleaner and easier to reason about.

```
const checkedCategories = [];
categories.forEach(cat => {
  let isVisible = false;
  cat.products.forEach(product => {
    const image = images.getDefault(product.imageTypes);
    isVisible = isVisible || !!image;

  });
  checkedCategories.push(Object.assign({}, cat, { visible: isVisible });
};
```

Comment: it's cleaner but i got the same error
//error cannot add property visible, object is not extensible

Comment: Sorry, should it be used checkedCategories for that whole thing? It isn't clear from the original question

Comment: Did you `freeze` your objects at some point?  Instead of assigning `visible`, you can create a new Object.

Comment: i use strict mode and i have to use this mode but how to do what i want in this way?

I wanted to create new object with extra key (visible if image exists) and then loop  this new object to render only <Products /> when key visible exists.

Comment: @DawidKwiatoń I updated my answer to create a new object.

Comment: Yes, i created new object 'checkedCategories' based on old object 'categories'